# How can I keep tab key behavior with this custom checkbox?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I created a custom checkbox on [this site](https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/) and I am trying to use it with tabindex, but I know that this CSS uses `display: none` which doesn't allow taborder, so this is my question: How can I use this custom checkbox in a form while keeping the input's properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the `tabindex`to the label that is standing in for the checkbox and then attach a keyboard event to the label to toggle the checkbox when a key is pressed. In this example I am toggling it when the user presses the space bar, like a real checkbox would do.

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById('myonoffswitch'),
  label = document.querySelector('#myonoffswitch + label');


label.addEventListener('keypress', function (evt) {
  if (evt.key === ' ') {
    checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
  } else if (evt.key === 'Enter') {
    // .form returns a reference to the parent form
    checkbox.form.submit();
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 90px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #2E8DEF; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC; color: #333333;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 25px; margin: 2.5px;
    background: #000000;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 56px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

```html
<form id="theform">
<input><br>
<br>
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch" tabindex="0">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div><br>
<input><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="normal-checkbox"><label for="normal-checkbox">Normal Checkbox</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked, but when I press enter to submit form while checkbox (label) is focused, nothing happens... but its ok anyway, thanks again!

Comment: @MatheusMachado I've updated it to support submitting via the enter key. You just need to check for the enter key in the keyboard event and then use the form's `submit` method.

Comment: @MatheusMachado One note about the [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) method, in most browsers the `submit` method does not trigger the submit event, so if you have validation of some sort in the submit event you would need to do that validation in the keypress event too before calling the `submit` method.

Comment: Thank you so much, helped a lot!